# Specifying custom URL schema in appengine using app.yaml?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url-rewriting

I am trying to have a custom URL which looks like this:

example.com/site/yahoo.com

which would hit this script like this=

example.com/details?domain=yahoo.com

can this be done using app.yaml?

the basic idea is to call "details" with the input "yahoo.com"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really rewrite the URLs *per se*, but you can use regular expression groups to perform a similar kind of thing.

In your app.yaml file, try something like:

```
handlers:
- url: /site/(.+)
  script: site.py
```

And in your site.py:

```
SiteHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, site):
        # the site parameter will be what was passed in the URL!
        pass

def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/site/(.+)', SiteHandler)], debug=True)
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)
```

What happens is, whatever you have after `/site/` in the request URL will be passed to `SiteHandler`'s `get()` method in the `site` parameter.  From there you can do whatever it is you wanted to do at /details?domain=yahoo.com, or simply redirect to that URL.

Comment: Note that the regex in app.yaml can be anything that matches, and it doesn't need the capturing parens. Commonly, you'd just use .* to send everything to your script, and use more specific regexes (with the capturing parens) in your WSGI app.